# setting id, name from DB to dropdown in angular js

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

I have select query as below..

```
var result = SqlMapper.Query<Object>(db, "SELECT PlaceID, PlaceName from Places order by PlaceName");
return result.AsEnumerable();
```

how do I set this result to dropdown in angularjs? Additionally, I need --select-- as text and 0 as value, to be initial value when page is loaded.

Comment: `<select ng-model="your_model" ng-options="place.PlaceId as place.PlaceName for place in result"><option value="0">--Select--</option></select>`

Comment: Update - that should be `place.PlaceID`

Comment: solved... actually value="0" doesn't work... have to specify value=""

Comment: yeah, thats right..I missed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually value="0" doesn't work... have to specify value="" as shown below.

```
<option value="">--Select--</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select ng-model="modelName" ng-options="result.PlaceID as result.PlaceName for result in results"></select>
```